# How do I generate a file of random (IEEE-754 single-precision) floats?

Tags: bash, random, floating-point, command-line-tool

In a bash script, I want to generate a file containing IEEE-754 single-precision floating point values (i.e not a text file). I want them to have a uniform distribution over some range (which I have as string variables, `$min_val` and `$max_val` ; e.g. `-100.0` and `200.0` respectively). I don't care that much about the "quality" of randomness, so anything passable to the naked human eye will do; and I don't want NaNs or infinities.

What's a convenient way to do that? I can't just user random characters from `/dev/urandom` and such.

Notes:

- You may assume the minimum and maximum and not subnormal.
- Other reasonable assumptions can be made, but please make them explicitly.

Comment: Are the _minimum_ and/or _maximum_ part of the range of generated random numbers?  E.g. Consider [1.0 ... 2.0] is hard to do well, where as [1.0 ... 2.0) is much easier. (2.0 not part of the later set.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: No, they aren't. Also, the former should not be too hard to do well: Generate a number in [0.0 .. 1.0), then flip a coin for whether to add it to 1.0 or subtract it from 2.0.

Comment: Re: [flip a coin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73097621/how-do-i-generate-a-file-of-random-ieee-754-single-precision-floats?noredirect=1#comment129164301_73097621), Then minimum and maximum occur 1/2 as frequent as other values.  Guess that is OK given "don't care that much about the "quality" of randomness"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Perl seems to pack floats into the IEEE-754 format.

You may need to change this for endian-ness:

```
perl -e '
    ($min,$max,$count) = @ARGV;
    print pack "f*", $min + rand($max-$min) for 1..$count;
' $min $max $count > floatfile
```

For reference:

```
perl -e 'print pack "f*", Inf, Nan, -118.625, 0.15625' | od -x
```

gives, on my machine:

```
0000000 0000 7f80 0000 ffc0 4000 c2ed 0000 3e20
0000020
```

`"f<*"` forces little-endian; `"f>*"` forces big-endian.